# R: Saving a graph with ggsave after using north2() to create map with north arrow

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I'm very new to R so any help would be greatly appreciated! I want to save my map with the north arrow ,after I create it, with the ggsave function. However, in my map I use the function north2() from the ggsn package and its only saving the map and not the north arrow.. I know I'm probably missing something very simple but I can't seem to figure it out. What am I doing wrong?? Thanks in advance.

```
graph1<-ggplot()+
  geom_polygon(data=df,colour="black",aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group,fill=ALG))+
  ggtitle("Figure 2.2A: Assessment Results for\nGeneral Aquatic Life Use, Spatial Extent")+
  xlab("")+
  ylab("")+
  coord_equal()+
  coord_fixed(ratio = 1)+
  ggsn::scalebar(df,location="bottomleft",dist = 50,st.dist=0.02,st.size=3, height=0.01)+
  scale_fill_manual("Aquatic Life Designated\nUse 2014 Assessment",values=c((values=c(colors))))+
  cowplot::background_grid(major= "none",minor = "none") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.y = element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position=c(0.8,0.1),
        panel.border = element_rect(fill=NA),
        legend.background = element_blank(),
        legend.text = element_text(size=7),
        legend.title = element_text(colour="black", size=8, face="bold"),
        plot.title=element_text(size=15, face="bold",vjust=1.0,hjust = .3))

ggsave(file="Figure 2.2A.pdf",width=11.5,height=8)
north2(graph1, x = 0.73, y = 0.89, scale = 0.1, symbol = 3)
dev.off()
```

Comment: The code looks like it's only saving the map, not the north arrow, but without reproducible data we can't test out to see what's actually happening. I have a good idea, though, which I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @Aaron Sorry that's what I meant! It's saving the map but not the north arrow with it.

Comment: Try moving the `north2` command before `ggsave`. And I don't think you need `dev.off()`.

Comment: @Lyngbakr, that's what I thought at first too, but `north2` is a funny variant that doesn't have usual ggplot behavior.

Comment: @Aaron Ah, I see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the base function `pdf` instead of `ggsave`.

```
pdf(file="Figure 2.2A.pdf",width=11.5,height=8)
north2(graph1, x = 0.73, y = 0.89, scale = 0.1, symbol = 3)
dev.off()
```

This is because the `north2` function works in a somewhat non-standard way; it plots the resulting plot instead of returning it. In the help it explains why this variant exists.

The plain `north` function is more standard; you would add this to your plot instead, like

```
graph1 + north(data=df, ...)
```

Then you could use the `ggsave` function as expected (after this, though, not before).

Note that for traditional plots you open the file first with `pdf()`, then run your plotting code, then close the file with `dev.off`; but for ggplots, you make your plot first and then call `ggsave`, with no `dev.off` needed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! Being a newbie to coding and R, little things like this confuse me.